# Can I hide all comments from a particular user on friend's posts on my Facebook feed?

Tags: facebook

There are a couple "friends-of-friends" that just give me the [heebie-jeebies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heebie-jeebies_%28idiom%29). Often I'll see their comments on my friend's posts on my feed. Is there any way that I can hide these from my view? I'm only looking to affect how it appears to me - I realize I cannot actually remove their comments from others posts.

Answer (score 1):

You could block the respective user(s).

> **[If I share mutual friends with the user I am blocking, will they be able to see my comments to this mutual friend?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=212761895411618)**
>
> Blocking allows you to prevent most interactions with someone on Facebook. People you block won't be able to find you in searches, view your profile, or contact you with pokes, Wall posts, or personal messages. In addition, they will not be able to see your Wall posts, comments on mutual friends’ Walls, or that you are a member of the same group as them.

However, this might not work in certain situations:

> **[Why am I able to see content added by a user that I've blocked on the site?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=166765783384329)**
>
> Blocking a user will prevent any type of direct interaction between you and that user. However, for technical reasons, there are certain instances when an individual you have blocked from your account may be able to view your comments on the site and vice versa, including comments on a mutual friend's photo. Please be assured that your listing will appear in black text, with no profile picture visible or contact links available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Better Facebook Plugin (or a similar extension) and see if there is a filter that will remove any instance of that friend. On second thought, since it is a friend of a friend then I don't think Better Facebook has that option.

Your best bet is to find an extension that removes comments based on a Facebook user id.